# Confusion on where my error is in my solution of $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ without the use of l'hospitals

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to ask something with respect to the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\ln x}$$
so if I do it with a calculator I get $L=0$ but my question is why I can't do this
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\ln x}=\left(\frac{\ln x }{x}\right)^{-1} = \frac{\ln((x-1)+1)}{x-1}\frac{(x-1)}{x}\to1\times1=1$$
by using the notable limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ln(x+1)}{x}=1$

where does this logic fall down

Edit: after reading the comments i realized that i was messing everything up, and confusing myself with the limt with basic problems.
Thank you

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: Why $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}{h+1}=1$ and why $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h+1}{h}=1$ ? this is completely wrong...

Comment: I don't follow your logic. Why does $\frac{\ln((x-1)+1)}{x+1}\cdot\frac{x+1}{x}\to 1\cdot 1$?

Comment: “Why can’t I do this?” I don’t see how you think you can. There is a lot of abuse of notation there. The big question first: Does $\frac x{x+1}\to 1$ as $x\to 0?$ But also, it is not true that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{\log x}=\left(\frac {\log x}x\right)^{-1},\tag1$$ since the left side is a limit. Then you use an arrow $\to$ to somehow change the right side of $(1)$ to an expression with $\log$ in the numerator?

Comment: Given your edit: Does $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-1}x=1?$$ You might be misapplying L’Hopital here if you think it is.

Comment: Your edit is still abuse of notation. It is true that $\log x/x$ is the product of your terms, but $=$ is incorrect here, because the left side of the equality has that $(\cdot)^{-1}.$ Your original error was using an arrow to indicate your next step, when an arrow has a specific meaning when we are specifically writing out limits. Use words more often than symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really looks like your argument is trying to say: $$\frac{\log x}{x}=\frac{\log(1+(x-1))}{x-1}\cdot \frac{x-1}{x}\tag 1$$ and the two terms go to $1$ as $x\to 0.$

But the two terms don’t go to $1.$ In the first term, it is true that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}=1.\tag2$$ But if $h=x-1,$ then as $x\to 0,$ $h\to-1.$ So $(2)$ does not apply.

Similarly, $\frac{x-1}x$ does not converge to $1.$

You might be misapplying L’Hopital. L’Hopital requires $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to converge to an “indeterminate form,” here requiring either both $f(x),g(x)\to 0$ or $f(x),g(x)\to\pm\infty.$

But $x-1\to-1$ as $x\to 0,$ so neither term qualifies for L’Hopital.

---

A quick argument that the limit of $\frac{\log(x)}x$ can’t be $1$ (or positive) is that for $0<x<1,$ $\log(x)<0,$ so $\frac{\log x}x<0,$ and the limit, if it exists, can’t be positive.

Comment: Thank you very much! then if it isn't too much to ask, how should I proceed, because I'm not finding anthing to work with

Comment: That’s really a separate question. My first inclination is to let $x=e^{-y}$ then $y\to\infty$ and you want to compute: $$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{-ye^y}$$ But $ye^y\to\infty.$

Comment: An easier proof is just to figure out $\lim_{x\to0+} x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0+}\log x=-\infty$ Since the quotient $\frac{0}{-\infty}$  is not an indeterminate form, you can calculate the limit as $0.$

Comment: More generally, if $f:[0,a]\to\mathbb R$ for some $a,$ is bounded then $$\lim_{x\to0+}{f(x)}{\log x}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can't* apply l'Hôpital to this limit. The numerator has limit $0$ and the denominator has limit $-\infty$, hence you have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\ln x}=0
$$
and your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\ln x}=\lim_{x\to0}x\frac{1}{\ln x}=0\cdot0=0
$$

Let's see where you went wrong. Transforming
$$
\dfrac{\ln x}{x}=\frac{\ln((x-1)+1}{x-1}\frac{x-1}{x}
$$
does not really simplify things, because for the first fraction you get
$$
\lim_{y\to-1}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}
$$
which is definitely not $1$, but $\infty$ (it's a limit from the right, of course). Similarly,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x-1}{x}=-\infty
$$
so you can conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln x}{x}=-\infty
$$

Comment: But when I calculate it with wolframalpha i get that the limit is equal to $0$, so isn't $-\infty$ wrong?

Comment: @Ramirogenta I reversed the fraction like you did. Now I added the explicit computation at the beginning.